# How to use field value of joined table for join rather than foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a new database schema that I need to query and I am having trouble getting the data I need without using a primary key in the JOIN. I didn't design the schema but I have to work with it. I tried creating a SQLFiddle for this but it kept giving me a gateway error when I tried.

Basically I have a Contacts table that contains ALL the contacts stored in the database. The Contacts table contains two fields that reference the tables that the contact is linked to (Vendor and Client). The Contact table also contains a field named "ContactType". This links to another table that defines the type of Contact (Owner or Employee).

```
[Client]
ClientID | Name
==============================
1        | Uptown Dining
2        | Downtown Eatery
3        | Midtown Steakhouse

[Vendor]
VendorID | Name
==============================
1        | ABC Produce
2        | DEF Seafood
3        | GHI Meats

[ContactType]
ContactTypeID | Name
==============================
1             | Owner
2             | Employee

[Contact]
ContactID | TableName | TableID | ContactTypeID | FirstName | LastName
========================================================================
    1     | Client    |    1    |       1       | Bob       | Smith
    2     | Vendor    |    1    |       1       | Jill      | Weston
    3     | Vendor    |    1    |       2       | Alice     | Jenkins
    4     | Client    |    2    |       1       | Chris     | Brown
    5     | Vendor    |    3    |       2       | Todd      | Davis
```

What I am trying to do is get a list of Client contacts who are the owners of their company. This SQl works to do just that.

```
SELECT 
  Contact.FirstName,
  Contact.LastName
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN Contact
  ON Client.ClientID = Contact.TableID 
  AND Contact.TableName = 'Client' 
  AND Contact.ContactTypeID = 1
```

This would give me ..

```
Bob Smith
Chris Brown
```

The problem is I don't want to use `AND Contact.ContactTypeID = 1` in the `JOIN`. I want to be able to use `Owner` or `Employee` in place of the `primary key (1 or 2)` of the `ContactType` table in the `JOIN` but I am unsure of how to do this. Please keep in mind the restriction needs to be in the `JOIN` since I need to reserve the `WHERE` clause to filter specific clients.

For example what if I wanted to query for a specific Vendor and get a list of the owner and employee in the same row ...

```
Vendor Name | Owner First | Owner Last | Employee First | Employee Last
============================================================================
ABC Produce |     Jill    |    Weston  |       Alice    |     Jenkins
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but if I'm reading it right - you want to have the chance to specify "Owner" or "Employee" explicitly in your `WHERE` clause rather than `1` or `2`.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  Contact.FirstName,
  Contact.LastName
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN Contact
  ON Client.ClientID = Contact.TableID 
  AND Contact.TableName = 'Client' 
LEFT JOIN ContactType ct ON ct.ContactTypeID = Contact.ContactTypeID
-- Now you can use it directly, as below
WHERE ct.Name = 'Owner'
```

**Edit: Response to your comment**

Not without getting messy... You can use a derived inline table, or a view, but all of these would be performance killers. The least performance-impairing (but still ugly) way I can think of is something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Contact.FirstName,
  Contact.LastName
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN Contact
  ON Client.ClientID = Contact.TableID 
  AND Contact.TableName = 'Client' 
  AND Contact.ContactTypeID = (SELECT iix.ContactTypeID FROM ContactType iix WHERE iix.Name = 'Owner')
```

Comment: You are correct in what I am trying to accomplish. Is there any way to accomplish this in the `JOIN` rather than the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @webworm Not in a clean way. But please see my edit.